# Manipular duas listas de um componente Drag and Drop em diferentes ManagedBeans

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Estou utilizando o componente DataTable Drag And Drop. Contextualizando é o seguinte:

Tenho um cadastro baseado em passos. Onde no primeiro passo insiro as informações de um Edital X, o que é manipulado pelo editalBean, já no segundo passo eu tenho o componente Drag and Drop com as Disciplinas a serem escolhidas, até ai tudo bem. Se eu fizer que nem sugere a [documentação](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dnd/dataTable.xhtml) eu consigo fazer funcionar numa boa. Mas eis que vem o problema: O método do meu disciplinasBean precisa que seja passado um centro (entidade) como parâmetro e esse centro está no editalBean. A minha solução foi colocar a lista de disciplinas selecionadas no disciplinasBean e a lista completa de disciplinas no editalBean (que é onde eu posso passar o parâmetro).

O método que manipula essas duas listas é esse (quando estão na mesmo bean):

```
public void onDisciplinaDrop(DragDropEvent ddEvent) {
        Disciplina disciplina = ((Disciplina) ddEvent.getData());

        listaSelecionadoss.add(disciplina);
        listaCompleta.remove(disciplina);
    }
```

Então a disciplina é adicionada em uma tabela e removida de outra. Mas como eu coloquei a lista completa de disciplinas em outro bean, eu não sei como removê-la.

O meu método onDisciplinaDrop está no disciplinaBean e a minha listaCompleta está no editalBean. Como posso fazer para fazer a remoção correta?

Meus códigos:

**EditalBean.java**

```
@ManagedBean(name="editalBean")
@SessionScoped
public class EditalBean {

    private Edital edital;
    private EditalDAO editalDAO = new EditalDAO();
    private Centro centro;
    private CentroDAO centroDAO = new CentroDAO();
    private DisciplinaDAO disciplinaDAO = new DisciplinaDAO();

    private List<Disciplina> listaPorCentro;

    public List<Disciplina> getListaPorCentro() {
        listaPorCentro = disciplinaDAO.getListaDisciplinaPorCentro(edital.getAno(), edital.getPeriodo(), centro);
        return listaPorCentro;
    }

    public void setListaPorCentro(List<Disciplina> listaPorCentro) {
        this.listaPorCentro = listaPorCentro;
    }
```

**DisciplinaBean.java**

```
@ManagedBean(name="disciplinaBean")
@SessionScoped
public class DisciplinaBean {

    private Disciplina disciplina;
    private Disciplina disciplinaSelecionada;
    private List<Disciplina> droppedDisciplinas = new ArrayList<Disciplina>();
    private DisciplinaDAO disciplinaDAO = new DisciplinaDAO();

    public void onDisciplinaDrop(DragDropEvent ddEvent) {
        if(droppedDisciplinas != null){
            droppedDisciplinas.add(d);
        }else {
            System.out.println("droppedDisciplinas é nulo.");
        }
    }
```

Se precisarem de mais detalhes tento explicar melhor. Obrigado.

Comment: A necessidade geral eu entendi mas o problema específico não ficou claro pra mim. Imagino que sua dificuldade esteja em usar em um Bean os objetos que foram instanciados em outro Bean. É isso? Duas sugestões: considere usar um único bean para recursos de uma mesma página que interagem tanto entre si; e considere usar ViewScoped pois SessionScoped pode prejudicar bastante a experiência do usuário.

Comment: Bom dia @Caffé, o meu problema é exatamente esse, através do DisciplinaBean conseguir manipular um objeto que está no EditalBean, então o melhor seria eu criar um Bean tipo: formCadastroBean (já que é um form de cadastro) e dentro dele eu trabalhar com os dois beans? É mais ou menos isso? E qual a diferença entre Session Scoped e View Scoped, eles interferem nisso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Então sua dificuldade é acessar em um Bean os objetos que foram instanciados em outro Bean

Para atender às requisições do usuário em recursos tão interligados em uma mesma página, não há problema em utilizar o mesmo bean e recomendo que o faça, assim você elimina a necessidade de injetar objetos de um bean em outro, o que gera um código bastante esquisito.

Entretanto, se você quer utilizar dois beans, uma maneira de injetar a instância de um bean em outro bean é:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class DisciplinaBean {

    //...

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{editalBean}")
    private EditalBean editalBean;

    // É esquisito, mas este set é necessário
    public void setEditalBean(EditalBean editalBean) {
        this.editalBean = editalBean;
    }

    private void metodoQualquerUsandoOBeanIntegado() {
        Centro centro = editalBean.getCentro();
    }
    
    //...
```

}

**Observação:** você não precisa passar `name="editalBean"` para anotação `@ManagedBean` da classe `EditalBean`, pois por convenção o nome da instância deste bean já será de fato `editalBean`, de modo que você está se repetindo.

**Outra observação:** procure utilizar beans **ViewScoped** em vez de **SessionScoped**. A vantagem é que um ViewScoped é criado na requisição da página e seu escopo limita-se a um tab do navegador, enquanto o SessionScoped dura por toda a sessão e além de os objetos não serem recolhidos da memória o usuário pode ter uma experiência ruim ao tentar trabalhar em duas tabs ao mesmo tempo.

SessionScoped deve ser usado apenas para dados da sessão de fato, como para as preferências do usuário e suas credenciais.

Lembrando que para o meu código acima funcionar, ele precisa que o `EditalBean` seja de fato de um escopo abrangente, tal qual o SessionScoped que você está utilizando. Então, recaptulando minha sugestão geral:

## Conclusão:

Utilize um único bean para tratar interações do usuário com recursos muito integrados de uma mesma página, assim você evita de precisar injetar um bean no outro (que resultaria em um código ruim) e evita de ter que usar **SessionScoped**, podendo usar **ViewScoped** que facilita melhor utilização da memória disponível e favorece uma melhor experiência do usuário.

Comment: Deu certinho. Muito obrigado @Caffé, excelente resposta!